# How to get good visibility in Single-photon_interference?

Tags: experimental-physics, quantum-optics, photonics

This question is specific to the experimental quantum optics community. I am attempting to perform a Mach-Zehnder interference experiment using single photons as a source. However, I am encountering difficulties. While I do observe the visibility pattern typical of single-photon interference, the visibility is quite low, in fact, less than 55%, and it is not stabilized. Any comments and suggestions regarding this issue would be highly appreciated.